# How to retrive an auto-generated entity key created into google app engine endpoint?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, key, entity, google-cloud-endpoints

We are implementing an android project with GAE, we created an entity in AppEngine project and we want to use it in the client side. We need to retrieve the key of the entity just created.

Entity code:

```
@Entity
public class Poll {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key keyPoll;
private String title;
private String creator;
private Date creationDate;
private String close;

public Key getKeyPoll() {
    return keyPoll;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getCreator() {
    return creator;
}

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public String getClose() {
    return close;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setCreator(String creator) {
    this.creator = creator;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date date) {
    creationDate = date;
}
public void setClose(String state) {
    close = state;
}
}
```

Client code:

```
  private class PollTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                  //Entity creation
          Poll poll = new Poll();


                  poll.setCreator("Bill");
          poll.setCreationDate(new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis()));
          poll.setTitle(title);
          poll.setClose("n");

          Pollendpoint.Builder builder = new Pollendpoint.Builder(
              AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
              null);

          builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);

          Pollendpoint endpoint = builder.build();


          try {
            endpoint.insertPoll(poll).execute();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

                  //this is another entity that store in its field "pollK" the key of
                  // the previous entity "poll"
          PollImg pollImg = new PollImg();


          pollImg.setPollK(poll.getKeyPoll());
          pollImg.setImageK(imageKey);

          Pollimgendpoint.Builder imgBuilder = new Pollimgendpoint.Builder(
              AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
              null);

          imgBuilder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(imgBuilder);

          Pollimgendpoint imgEndpoint = imgBuilder.build();


          try {
            imgEndpoint.insertPollImg(pollImg).execute();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }


          return null;
        }
      }
```

The problem is that poll.getKeyPoll() return a null value even if the entity "poll" is correctly created and visible on the server.

Code of insertPoll method:

```
/**
 * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
 * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
 * It uses HTTP POST method.
 *
 * @param poll the entity to be inserted.
 * @return The inserted entity.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "insertPoll")
public Poll insertPoll(Poll poll) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {

        mgr.persist(poll);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return poll;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected answer : From the code that you have shown, the object `poll` is a local object which you created first and then sent it over the wire to insert into the App Engine backend. Your `insertPoll` method looks fine.

However, you cannot expect that the code will automagically populate the Key field for your `poll` object because the object is still local and nothing more than that. To retrieve the actual value, you will need to look at the response value of the `endpoint.insertPoll(poll).execute();` in your code. This will return the Poll object, which you can then query to get the Key value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I posted the code of insertPoll method.